# microsoft.xmlhttp to pick up value of redirected url

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest

I am using scripting language and microsoft ActiveX

```
oxmlhttp = createobject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
```

to scrape html page. 
I also want to find the new url in my code to which my old url is redirected in a browser.

E.g.

http://www.comlaw.gov.au/ComLaw/Management.nsf/all/bytitle/AA40ED158FCF0A9BCA256F7100071796?OpenDocument

becomes

http://www.comlaw.gov.au/Series/C2004A00446

I can't see how I can collect it from methods this object exposes. Should I use something else for that ?

Comment: Why ? It is Visual Foxpro. I presume, it doesn't really matter any dynamic language on Windows which drives ActiveX will do. I meant alternative ActiveX which may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using Internet Explorer ActiveX

```
oie = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
oie.Navigate( old_url)
redirected_url = oie.LocationURL
```